# Is there an alternative to webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app which makes pretty heavy use of webview. My requirements are to be able to look at the html and to inject javascript into pages being loaded, even iframes. I've accomplished this with the webview that comes with android but it just isn't working great.

So are there other projects out there that provide the same html5 browsing experience but are a bit more developer friendly? Would it maybe be possible to take the open source web view code and build my own or is that just a crazy idea?

Thanks.

Comment: @DerGolem zirco-browser seems to be derived from WebView. How is it the alternative to WebView that mntgoat desires?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).
As described in its web site:

> With the platform variations in the market you are forced to assume
> that every Android WebView works differently. There are differences
> in:
>
> - Which JavaScript APIs are available
> - Support and syntax for CSS properties
> - How your application's interface is rendered …and plenty
>
> more. You want to support as many versions of Android as possible, but
> it’s frustrating and time consuming.
>
> There’s a better way. What if the only WebView you had to worry about
> was up to date with the latest version of Google Chromium? With
> Crosswalk, you can:
>
> - Develop around device fragmentation
> - Provide a feature rich experience on all Android 4.x devices
> - Easily debug with Chrome DevTools Improve
>   the performance of your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Comment: I agree that XwalkView is incredibly awesome with HTML5 and avoiding ridiculous WebView fragmentation across Android devices. However, it isn't without its problems... 1) offscreen rendering is non-existant 2) download of external resources (images) is single-threaded

Comment: Hello, I really find Crosswalk webview such a pain in the arse just to set it up. I wanted to Embed XWalkView so I could use it on my project. It took me one month experimenting on various WebViews for <Android 4.4 and this one took me at least 1 week and still no success.  I don't know, followed every bit article from the web esp this one but still no luck: https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/ Their documentation is garbage. I don't really recommend this Crosswalk. If you are a developer on a limited 'TIME' budget and decided to use Crosswalk for embedding. NO

Comment: I agree with Neon Warge. I manage to embed Crosswalk but when app goes background it loses it state. Restore state function doesn't work.

Comment: Note that Crosswalk is not maintained since Jan 2017

Answer (score 9):

#### I had a similar need to get an alternative to WebView.

### Found `GeckoView` based on GeckoEngine by Mozilla.

Pros:

- GeckoView is designed to expose the entire power of the Web to applications, and all that through a straightforward API.
- Better Performance over WebView. Far Better with performance for Graphis Intensive WebApps.
- Strong Mozilla Community behind the development.
- Capable to let you make your own Web Browser for Android.

Cons:

- Your App Size will get an additional 50MB or something, as the `GeckoView` comes loaded with GeckoEngine native to your app.
- Fewer Examples and Tutorials on YT or Web.

### Following Docs will help you get started.

#### Official Doc:

https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/

#### 101 Guide Blog :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1381698-android-tutorial-for-geckoview-getting-started

#### Community Chat Forum: Ask your Questions and Join `GeckoView` Community.

https://chat.mozilla.org/#/room/#geckoview:mozilla.org

Answer (score 0):

In android 4.4, a new webview is introduced based off of chromium. 
However if you are developing for previous versions of android as well you can check out this library that is also based off of chromium https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview
with chromium, your webview will support HTML5, CSS3 and javascript

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll take a look at that github project. In reality one of my biggest problems is the switch to chromium google made, there is one big issue with it relating to getting cookies during the intercept of a request which is heart of my app.

Comment: I looked at that project.  It says, do not use for product.  I think this may be the issue, though, because I'm running my app on my phone and my friend's phone.  I have a GS3 which is Android 4.3.  He has a GS4 and doesn't see the issues that I do.

Comment: How is this experimental (!) chromium_webview better than the official [WebView for Android](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) that is also based on Chromium?

Comment: Looks like the project is dead. Last commit was a year old :/

Comment: Last commit was 2015.. worse than Crosswalk though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Chrome Custom Tabs** as a best option for handling third party Website on same app. And off course it is feature loaded. Like sharing chrome cookies, data saving option as with chrome

Comment: As far as I know you can not look at the html and/or inject javascript with Chrome Custom Tabs which is a main requirement I have listed on this post.