# chrome app 'webview' alternative in HTML5

Tags: html, webview, google-chrome-app

After getting the news that **Google will drop the support for chrome packed app**

[More information here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/19/google-phasing-chrome-apps-will-no-longer-work-2018/)

I'm planning to convert my **packed app** with **navtive HTML5**.

The application uses webviews to host different websites, 
And im looking for alternative to the webviews with HTML5

**Is there any solid alternative to webviews in HTML?**

Comment: Just a recommendation, you can try to check [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/). With this Crosswalk Project, it has these advantages: Get consistent, predictable behavior by reducing Android device fragmentation, Use the latest web innovations and APIs. Provide a feature rich experience on all Android 4.0+ devices, Easily debug with Chrome DevTools and Improve the performance of your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. For more information, check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459735/is-there-an-alternative-to-webview).

Comment: I'm talking about chrome app 0_0

Answer (score 0):

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) is a good alternative to chrome. Its built on the same underlying tech. You can have desktop apps using it.

An sandboxed iframe is a good alternative to iframes. Read more over [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/)

Comment: Yes I know, I'm looking for HTML5 solution ( As mantioned in the question ), or atleast in browser solution. And sandboxed iframe is not nearly similar to iframe neither in the features nor the 'under the hood'. But thanks any way

Answer (score -1):

The *iframe* tag is the corresponding equivalent in HTML.

The webview documentation compares iframes to webviews.
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

You can add more isolation by sandboxing the iframe.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: Iframe is not equivalent to webview, in many ways (API, Environment variables, and many more). This is by the way both are available in chromeApp. I'm 99% percent that there is no answer for that, but I waiting for new solution in the min it will be available.

Comment: what do u think is the diff between iframe and webview

Comment: (1) webview it runs on a differant process opposed to iframe that runs on the same process, (2) webview runs as indipanded window opposed to ifram that runs as a child of the parent window (3) webview have reach API that lets you listen/manipulate requests, listen to loading states (much more states then ready-state). and the list goes on..

Comment: This is the quote from the link you provided (saw it after) : "Different from the iframe, the webview runs in a separate process than your app; it doesn't have the same permissions as your app and all interactions between your app and embedded content will be asynchronous. This keeps your app safe from the embedded content."